# How many Levels (kind) of clothing wear are there? Are there benefits associated?

Tags: banished

How many levels of wear do we have for clothing?
So far, I've found two:

- Ragged ('zerlumpt'/'zerfetzt' in German)
but there is no visual difference to

- Excellent

If citizens wear excellent clothes do they need less firewood in their homes? Do you know any other advantages?

Comment: I believe the different condition levels you're describing are simply how much longer until the person needs to go replace their clothing. I don't think these conditions have any direct effect on the person though. These levels are all the same for each different type of clothing as well, they're just a progression from essentially "New" to "Old"

Answer (score 2):

Clothing expires over time. I'm unsure how long they last but a large population will need a constant supply of new clothing

3 levels of clothing

Ragged - (effectively no clothing) This is what newborns have until they pick up some.

Fair - Leather or wool

Excellent - Leather and wool (can stay outside in the cold longer)

Clothing does not affect how much firewood is used.

Occupied houses appear to constantly use firewood - Rate varies - I think rate depends on season/temperature. Stone houses use less.

Answer (score 1):

There's two types of clothing:

- Normal clothing (either from wool or hides, you choose which to use), it offers less warmth so citizens stay outside in the cold less
- Warm clothing (from both wool and hides), it offers more protection to the elements so citizens work for longer. This is obviously the more efficient route if you can sustain it.

[Source](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Clothing)

Comment: I think the question is about degrees of wear the clothing suffers.

Comment: I took the question to ask what clothing does, with firewood usage being just a hand-waving example. To be clear, clothing doesn't have any direct effect on firewood usage (but since they stay indoors less, they'll burn less wood).